# in operator not working properly with useValue in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dependencies, code-injection

I am using the `useValue` in dependency injection.

> {
> provide: I18N_LANGUAGE_KEY,
> // useValue: config && 'language_keys' in config ? config.language_keys : language_key,
> // useValue: config && config.i18nLanguageKey,
> useValue: !('i18nLanguageKey' in config) ? i18nLanguageKey : config.i18nLanguageKey, },

default value is:

> export const i18nLanguageKey: I18nLanguageKeys = {
> I18N_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-available-language',
> I18N_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-default-language',
> I18N_TRANSLATE_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-translate-language', };

but want to pass the changed value from config also.
in forRoot method of the module:

> I18nModule.forRoot({
> i18nLanguageKey: {
> I18N_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-available-language1',
> I18N_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-default-language2',
> I18N_TRANSLATE_LANGUAGE_KEY: 'i18N-translate-language3',
> },
> }),

But not able to get the new passed value, overall ---->  `useValue: !('i18nLanguageKey' in config) ? i18nLanguageKey : config.i18nLanguageKey`, is always giving the i18nLanguageKey (which is default) and not going in the else part. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

This finally works if i use the pipe operator (OR) in the useValue.

{
provide: I18N_LANGUAGE_KEY,
useValue: ( config && config.i18nLanguageKey ) || i18nLanguageKey,
}